# When upload CSV file to S3 with Multipart, uploaded csv file has http header

Tags: csv, http, amazon-s3, multipartform-data

I got a problem when uploading a CSV file to S3 with multipart/form-data header on Postman.

[image]
[image]

after uploading CSV to s3 with multipart and download it, I can see some HTTP header in CSV file.
but it does not happen upload with text/CSV header.

here's what I've done. my application based on node.js(nest.js)

1. Node.js -> Create Presigned S3 URL which called 'A' -> PUT 'A' with multipart header -> Uploaded csv file has HTTP header
2. Node.js -> Create Presigned S3 URL which called 'A' -> PUT 'A' with text/csv header -> OK
   [image]

I think, it's related with multipart boundary, but not sure.
please, give me a clue

thank you.

Comment: Had the same issue when I uploaded from my web application. Issue resolved after **I removed the headers** while uploading the file.